# creating my own jquery function, but it works for only one element?

Tags: jquery, html

I have defined my own function, like this:

```
jQuery.fn.createSelector = function(){
    var element = $(this[0]);
    // hide original selector
    $(element).hide();
    // create new selector
    $(element).after('<table class="selectorReplacer"><tr><td class="td01"></td><td class="td02"><div></div></td><td class="td03"></td></tr></table>');
};
```

Then I have applied it, like this:

```
$(".createSelector").createSelector();
```

In my HTML, i have MANY `<div class="createSelector">` divs, but the function is applied only to one (the first one in the code) of them.

How should I rewrite my function to have it applied to all the elements?

EDIT: One more problem.

I need to append more elements, let's say like this:

```
.after('<div id="div1">')
.after('<div id="div2">');
```

The problem is the result is reversed, so after insert, the HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="createSelector"></div>
<div id="div2">
<div id="div1">
```

How do I make them insert in the order I write them in the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside a plugin `this` is already a jQuery object, so you need not wrap it again, like this:

```
jQuery.fn.createSelector = function(){
    return this.hide().after('<table class="selectorReplacer"><tr><td class="td01"></td><td class="td02"><div></div></td><td class="td03"></td></tr></table>');
};
```

Note that by returning the result (which is still the same set in this case), it allows you to chain other jQuery functions on the end, for example:

```
$(".createSelector").createSelector().fadeIn();
```

*Why?* When you do `this[0]` you're saying from that jQuery object (`this`), take the *very first* DOM element and wrap *that* in a new jQuery object.  But...you don't want that, you want all matched elements, so just skip this step.

Comment: Godlike! Thanks a lot, I've got one more problem though. I'll edit my first post, hopefully you can help me, again ! :)

Comment: @RiMMER - In the future I'd ask this as a different question, as it throws all the answers/question off by changing it later.  For your issue though you would either need to put them in a single `.after()` as one html string, or put a `.next()` (per added element) in-between the `.after()` calls so you traverse to the element(S) your just added, then add stuff after *that* element, for example: `.after('<div id="div1" /><div id="div2"/>');` or `.after('<div id="div1">').next().after('<div id="div2">');`

Answer (score 3):

surely you drop the [0] from this and the wrapper too:

`var element = this;`

Comment: Wrapping `this` is unnecessary, as it's already a jQuery object (not a DOM element or raw array) when in a plugin context.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `this.hide().after("<your html>");` instead of doing `$(this[0])` which is effectively resolving to the first matched element.

Edit: to use chaining as it is one of JQuery's strengths.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery.fn.createSelector = function(){
    return this.each(function() {
        var element = $(this);
        // hide original selector
        element.hide();
        // create new selector
        element.after('<table class="selectorReplacer"><tr><td class="td01"></td><td class="td02"><div></div></td><td class="td03"></td></tr></table>');
    });
};
```

Comment: doing `$(this).each` is unnecessary as JQuery will apply the `hide` and `after` to all matched elements.

Comment: your solution works, but you have a syntax error in your code. you forgot to close the ``.each()`` function at the end. please, fix it in your post and I'll accept your solution. thx!!

Comment: @RiMMER - Please do not use this approach, there's a lot of wasted cycles here for no reason, see the above answers for how to greatly slim this down.

Answer (score 1):

Change the first line of your plugin to:

```
var element = this;
```

Since your function is a jQuery plugin extension, when it is called `this` will already be a jQuery wrapped element or list of elements (i.e. `this == $(".createSelector")`).  Therefore you don't need to wrap it in the `$()` selector.  That's why when you do `this[0]` it's selecting only the first element in the jQuery element list (i.e. `$(".createSelector")[0]`).